# attempting to create string of random values

Tags: c#, string, random

I'm trying to generate a string of a random length which consists out of random `char`s.

To do so I have this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            MyString test = new MyString();

            test.Random();
            Console.WriteLine(test.Value);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class MyString
{
    private string value = string.Empty;
    private Random r = new Random();

    public string Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set { this.value = value; }
    }

    public void Random()
    {
        int length = (r.Next() % (100)) + 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            value = value + RandomChar();
        }  
    }

    public char RandomChar()
    {
        // 32 to 126
        int c = (r.Next() % 95) + 32;
        char ch = (char)c;
        return ch;
    }
}
```

Now, lets look at a part of the output:

[image]

As you can see, the output is far from random, it contains a lot of repeating strings. How is this possible, and how do I solve it?

Comment: That's the thing about randomness, you can never know if it's not random.

Comment: That image is very hard to read.

Comment: Random.Next has three overloads, at least one of them should be of interest to you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13td4hz1.aspx

Comment: @NullUserException: Deadpan humor or not, there are ways to get enough distribution/independence that we don't care to distinguish between random and difficult to predict.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you are creating a *new* instance of the `Random` class every time your `MyString` constructor is called. The `Random` class probably seeds itself based on the current time (to some resolution). Random number generators seeded with the same value will generate the same pseudo-random sequence.

The solution is to construct *one* instance of `Random` and use that everywhere.

Comment: Good answer.  From the doc:  "However, because the clock has finite resolution, using the parameterless constructor to create different Random objects in close succession creates random number generators that produce identical sequences of random numbers."  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx

Comment: +1 As a quick fix, consider making your `Random` instance static -- it will likely change the distribution of characters since there is only one `Random` instance.

Comment: @r0h: Just don't use this in a cryptography scenario.  Probably great for test code, though.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename.aspx

```
string randomName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
randomName = randomName.Replace(".", string.Empty);

// take substring...
```